# DocuSign API - Java: List of Envelope-Sharings between Accounts (SharedAccess Envelope)

Tags: java, docusignapi

Because of legal requests, I have to deliver a report for permission audits in DocuSign on a regular basis.
While I have solved to query over the REST-API the permission profiles, Custody Tranfer targets and SigningGroups a user belongs to, I fail now with the envelopes shared by a user to another one.

General:

- I am using the "main" account the Docusign Environment is based on.
- DSAdmin Permission Profile.
- Token/Authentication:

  ```
   byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));
   java.util.List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>(2);
   scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
   scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION);

   ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(BASE_URL);


   OAuthToken oAuthToken =  
           apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(CLIENT_ID
                                       , API_USERNAME
                                               , scopes
                                               , privateKeyBytes
                                               , 3600);

   apiClient.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
  ```

This is running well. Then I try to access the sharings of the different users:

```
            AccountsApi accountsApi = new AccountsApi(apiClient);
        
        ListSharedAccessOptions listSharedAccessOptions = accountsApi.new ListSharedAccessOptions();
        listSharedAccessOptions.setItemType("envelopes");
        listSharedAccessOptions.setShared("shared_to,shared_from,shared_to_and_from");

        
        AccountSharedAccess accountSharedAccess = accountsApi.listSharedAccess(API_ACCOUNT_ID, listSharedAccessOptions);

        List<MemberSharedItems> memberSharedItemsList = accountSharedAccess.getSharedAccess();
        
        MemberSharedItems memberSharedItems = memberSharedItemsList.get(0); //  The size of this list is only 1

        List<SharedItem> sharedItemsList = memberSharedItems.getEnvelopes();
        
        for(SharedItem sharedItem : sharedItemsList) {
                System.out.println(sharedItem.getUser().getUserStatus() + " " + sharedItem.getShared() + " " + sharedItem.getUser().getEmail());
        }
```

As result I get the printout for several lines with `shared_from` and `shared_to_and_from` relative to the account I authenticated with. The result is correct.

But now I'd like to get these information as well for the other users I have in this environment. If I change the `accountId` in the `listSharedAccess()`-Arguments, I get a `{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user."}` as error back.

I guess the answer is very simple and I am only thinking to complicated, but I have no clue at the moment, how to list the sharings of the other users.

Here the REST-call and it's answer:

```
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/API_ACOUNT_ID/shared_access?item_type=envelopes&shared=shared_to%2Cshared_from%2Cshared_to_and_from
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Authorization: Bearer myLovelyJwtToken
1 > User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/3.11.0-RC2/java
1 > X-DocuSign-SDK: Java
```

And the answer:

```
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 200
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache
1 < Content-Length: 4797
1 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
1 < Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 17:59:16 GMT
1 < X-BurstLimit-Limit: 500
1 < X-BurstLimit-Remaining: 499
1 < X-DocuSign-Node: DADADADAD
1 < X-DocuSign-TraceToken: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
1 < X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
1 < X-RateLimit-Remaining: 995
1 < X-RateLimit-Reset: 1612980000
{"resultSetSize":"27","totalSetSize":"27","startPosition":"0","endPosition":"26","accountId":"API_ACCOUNT_ID","sharedAccess":[{"user":{"userName":"MyUsername","userId":"API_USERNAME","email":"my@email.address","userStatus":"Active"},"envelopes":[{"user":{"userName":"user1","userId":"API_USERNAME_user1","email":"user1@email.address","userStatus":"Active"},"shared":"shared_from"},{"user":{"userName":"user2","userId":"API_USERNAME_user2","email":"user2@email.address","userStatus":"Active"},"shared":"shared_to_and_from"}]}]}
```

I've shortened the Answer-JSON.

My question is simply: How do I get the information about the envelope-sharings between the different users, where my user I am logged in is not involved? (But all users belong to my DocuSign-Environment I am Admin of)

Thank you very much in advance!

Best Regards

Christian

Edit:
Found the answer myself: Sleeping a night about often helps: I've added the API_ACCOUNT_ID(s) of the users, I want to have this information to the `userIds` of the SharedAccessOptions and it works well.

Often the answer is so near.

Answer (score 0):

https://appdoc.app/artifact/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java/2.4.1/com/docusign/esign/api/AccountsApi.ListSharedAccessOptions.html
Has **userIds** property [`getUserdIDs()` or `setUserIds()` from caller] which enable you to specific a list of userIDs (GUID) for the users you want to get information on.
Note that to find the **userId**, you can make another call to `ListUsers()` for example, or you can manually find them in the [Apps and Keys](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys) page (**note** User ID not Account Id!)